# Access RPM database

Tags: linux, rpm

I would like to find where information is stored about which RPM packages are installed?

I know that there is a internal database for this. Can I access somehow this database with Java?

Comment: Can you tell us what you'd like to ***do*** with the DB information? Is there any reason the rpm userspace tools aren't sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/var/lib/rpm
It is a Berkeley DB.
The database is used to keep track of all files that are changed and created.

Details taken from
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager#Local_RPM_installation_database

Comment: Any more information how I can do this with Java?

Comment: Sorry, not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

They are stored in berkeley DB format, typically in `/var/lib/rpm`.

As far as I am aware there are no decent or maintained bindings for RPM in java. You can of course open the berkeley DB file in java and inspect it like that, but I suspect that might be a painful experience.

Comment: Any more information how I can do this with Java?

Comment: I think that question is more for stackexchange. Or you could use another language like python, perl or the C API.